# Ping in Android to detect device failing/departure

Tags: android, ping, battery

I've read [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/efficient-downloads/index.html) about data transfer in a battery efficient way.
All the lessons are based on one, simple concept: polling the server is Android is battery inefficient. For this reason, [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm) is introduced in order to send messages from the server to the device only when needed.

There is only one problem: I'm trying to implement a "mobile cloud", so a cloud composed by mobile devices, where each device can join/leave the network with high frequency. So I need some mechanism to detect when a device is not reachable anymore. Until now, in all the works that I've seen on the topic, the only solution was to periodically ping the main server to say "Hey, I'm still alive!" from the mobile device. Obviously this solution is battery killing, but until now I've not seen/found any better solution.

Do you know any battery efficient solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason why pinging the server periodically (heartbeat) is necessarily wasteful of the battery/inefficient. That depends upon how frequently you need to ping, and whether your ping needs to initiate its own transmission vs piggy backing on some other transmission.

Let me explain. Battery inefficiency depends upon whether or not you are increasing the frequency or duration of the transceiver being in an active state. If the transceiver is continually active anyway, such as it is continuously exchanging data or audio, then a heartbeat adds no additional burden. If it is not active, then there will be additional energy usage but that depends upon the frequency of your heartbeat compared to how long a ping will cause the transceiver to be powered. Even then, it's probably irrelevant to your application as I suspect "cloud" means the devices are active and connected.

Let's assume that your heartbeat is such that it will increase the duration of your transceiver being active. There are still techniques you can use to decrease this impact, such as caching your beat and sending it only when it can piggy back on another transmission. Of course, such solutions depend upon whether your heartbeat is implemented in an application, OS or kernel.

I suggest you do actual tests to see if there is truly an impact on your devices.

PS I'm not saying the tutorial is wrong. It isn't. But it is addressing a broader and more general problem then what you have.